# Laravel Passport, internal oAuth AFTER socialite login.?

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport, laravel-socialite

Can I run a scenario by you? I'm struggling with the data flow in my head... and what's possible.

I have an app. I also have a couple of different data cores (laravel apps) that will proved data to the app, but need to ensure the user is logged in to the parent app. I finally have a user data centre (another laravel app that is responsible for user logging and granting access etc).

so.

1. User logins in with Google/FB etc.
2. Using Laravel/Socialite, get a Google/FB access token. by loggin into user data center and running the required code.
3. Before I redirect back the user, I log an oauth request to the passport package on the same server.
4. Finally return to the app, an access token for the user data center.. no the original Social login (google/FB etc)
5. When the app then requests data from the primary data core, the data core will ping the user data center to check that the user is logged in.

Is this a sound strategy?
But mostly, how do authorise a user using passport, on the same server? I assume I don't perform a CURL request.. to itself?

I'm new to micro services... any general advice is welcome too.. but I'm excited for this new way of working!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this:
https://github.com/peterpetrus/passport-token

seemed to fit my purposes